# Debugging a simple jQuery document

Tags: jquery, css

here's another beginner question. I appreciate all the help the community offers. I've been staring and staring at this code for the last two hours and still can't figure out what's wrong with it. It's just a simple document, where a border is supposed to appear around hovered list items. Could anyone please tell me why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="EN" dir = "ltr" xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(init);

        function init(){
            $("li").hover(border, noBorder);
        } // end init

        function border(){
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid black");
        }

        function noBorder(){
            $(this).css("border", "0px none black");
        }

        //]]>
        </script>
        <title>hover.html</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hover Demo</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>alpha</li>
            <li>beta</li>
            <li>gamma</li>
            <li>delta</li>
        </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/QeGN8/ ..

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/6whLu/  Which browser are you using?  I did that jsFiddle with Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It works in Chrome. The code editor I've been experimenting with is Brackets Sprint 30, which is still a beta-proto for anyone reading that hasn't heard of it yet. I like brackets as a code editor, but the live preview feature of the program seems to have a bug that won't run some programs. Thanks for the help. Gotta try using that jFiddle thingy myself.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use CSS:

```
li:hover {
   border : 1px solid black
}
```

This is much cleaner and has less possibilities for bugs.